# ContentProvider Database not getting deleted

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm developing a content provider which stores its data in an SQLite database. During development, I need to change the schema, or delete the database entirely and have it rebuilt (I'm not upgrading the database at this stage of development).

I found the database file, stored at /data/data//databases/app_db . When I pull it to my desktop machine, I can use SqliteSpy to see its content and all is well. However, when I delete it, it doesn't always get *really* deleted. Although I can't see the file in DDMS or ADB, my application still sees it.

I tried to make sure my application and service aren't up when I delete the file, but it doesn't seem to help. In about half the times I delete the file, I need to restart the emulator for it to have effect.

What could be preventing the file from being really deleted?

Itay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this issue too when was writing unit tests for my `ContentProvider`s. You need to make sure you've killed the process that hosts `ContentProvider` that uses that specific database file. And only than delete it.

Comment: I tried it a couple of more times, this time making sure the application is down *before* deleting the file (yesterday I think I deleted the file and then shut the application done). It seems to work now. Thanks!